# match amounts together with wildcard desciption from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql

I need to return all values from one table where the amount matches a row in another table and those rows have similar descriptions. Some examples.

`table1` contains (note that the `description` field contains badly formatted text):

```
amount  | description
------------------------------------------------
 899,95 | 37.43.22.174                    COMPANY HOLDING         AMSTERDAM                        Regarding: speedtransaction        ORDERNUMBER: 0012345
3793,93 | Apple Lt. STREET 5 1234 AV AMSTERDAM 134567
3793,93 | Totally diff COMP lt. STREET 8 6542 AC HAARLEM 134567
```

`table2` contains:

```
amount  | description
------------------------------------------------
 899,95 | COMPANY HOLDING SEPA Ove
3793,93 | Apple Lt.
```

Amounts can be the same for multiple rows in the 2 tables, so I need to make the comparison with another value, being some keywords in the descriptions. How can I match those descriptions?

Tried this, but it doesn't work very well because I think I'm still selecting where the amount occurs in the other table:

```
SELECT `table1`.* FROM `table1`
WHERE `table1`.`amount` NOT IN
   (SELECT `amount`
    FROM `table2`
    WHERE `table2`.`amount` = `table1`.`amount`
      AND `table1`.`description` LIKE CONCAT('%', SUBSTR(`table2`.`description`, 1, 15), '%')
   )
```

Comment: I don't believe that there will be an easy way for you to accurately do this. I assume your trying to reconcile payment records from two different systems. It might be best to implement a semi-automated matching system if this is the case. I.e. The system creates links for direct matching records and suggests links for partially matching records and lets a user verify it's correct and manually create that link. And then show records without matches left over for someone to manually link them or flag them.

Comment: can you add more sample data to show multiple rows in 2 tables, and your expected result? right now it's giving you results because your LIKE is comparing 'COMPANY HOLDING SEPA Ove' LIKE '%37.43.22.174   %' which seem wrong.

Comment: Hi, some more values are:
table1: Amount: 3793,93 Description: Apple Lt. STREET 5 1234 AV AMSTERDAM 134567
Amount: 3793,93 Description: Totally diff COMP lt. STREET 8 6542 AC HAARLEM 134567
Table2: Amount: 3793,93 Description: Apple Lt.

Dont know how to add to the edited table in my post. I need to find the payment differences indeed. Amounts that cant be found in the other table. But can be the exact same.

Comment: @Snuur You might want to try setting up an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) example of your database. This will help people get a better idea of the problem and provide you with better answers.